# dsPIC: Link assembler project with XC16 in command line mode

Tags: pic, compiler, assembler

I have an assembler project that compiles and links fine with MPLABX. Now I am trying to build it from the command line. Attempt to use the command line from MPLABX fails.

When I am calling:

C:\MiscStuffs>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc16\v1.11\bin"\xc16-ld.exe -p30F3012 --defsym __ICD2RAM=1 --report-mem -o Test4.elf -Map Test4.map Test4.o

I get:

C:\MiscStuffs\Test4.o(.text+0x12): In function `__reset':
: undefined reference to`_PR2'
C:\MiscStuffs\Test4.o(.text+0x18): In function `__reset':
: undefined reference to`_IEC0'
C:\MiscStuffs\Test4.o(.text+0x1c): In function `__reset':
: undefined reference to`IC1CON'
....

And so on. When I remove `-p30F3012`, it starts complaining that `Memory region auxflash does not exist`. I tried putting wrong processor number. I get: `Error: unknown processor 30F3712`.  In other words, it understands what the current architecture is. But for some reason still cannot resolve addresses of the SFRs.

Should I specify any additional library? Is there any work around at all? If somebody managed to compile/link any assembler project with XC16, please, drop a line and the command line that you were using.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Very frustrating.